# Command to display only running processes in Linux

Tags: linux, ps

Can anyone provide the Linux command to display only the *running* processes? They should be only running and not in sleeping or other states.

Can we achieve it with the `ps` command?

I know `ps- aF` command will show the processor (PSR) column but will not show the states of the process.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html said there's an "r" option

Answer (score 1):

Using the BSD "personality" of `ps`:

```
ps axr
```

**a** all users, **x** include TTY-less processes, **r** running state — as noted in the comment by 炸鱼薯条德里克.

The BSD options do not use a dash, `ps` is an old, complicated program, it has a BSD personality that changes how it behaves.

The `-F` flag has a fixed set of columns, this is an alternative:

```
ps -axo uid,pid,ppid,c,sz,rss,psr,stat,stime,tty,time,cmd | 
  nawk '($8~/R/){print}'
```

which adds STAT after PSR, with a little awk to filter for "R" in column 8.

Comment: The parens and print are not necessary, as a missing action defaults to print.

Comment: The axr flags are the right way, not sure why you need awk because if you want to change the format you just use ps axro

I'm not sure why you want the run flag, generally, the reasons people want to filter by running processes get results they don't want. The issue being its a point in time (literally exactly when you read that processes' stat file) measurement.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -w R /proc/[0-9]*/stat`

The PID can be parsed from the filenames.

It's also good for finding processes in state D or Z.